# How to write the argmax in a minimax problem?

Tags: optimization, notation

Suppose that $\mathcal{X} = \{x_{1},x_{2}\}$ and $\mathcal{Y}=\{y_{1},y_{2}\}$ are two sets, each containing two real numbers.

Now suppose I have some function $f: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}$, and I want to solve the minimax problem:
\begin{align}\min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} f(x,y).\end{align}
What is the proper notation for the value of $y^* \in \mathcal{Y}$ that obtains in the inner maximum? Would it be proper to write:
$$ y^* = \min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \arg\max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} f(x,y)?$$

Comment: How about $y^*(x) \in \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{arg} \: \text{max}} \: f(x,y)$?

Comment: @madnessweasley thanks for your comment. I am not looking for $y^{*}(x)$, but am instead looking for the value of $y$ that obtains in the inner maximum after the full minimax problem is solved (not just the inner maximum). However, your comment was useful and gave me an idea, and I have posted a solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Let:
$$y^{*}(x) = \arg \max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} f(x,y)$$
Furthermore, let:
$$x^{*} = \arg\min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x,y^{*}(x))$$
Then the value of $y$ that obtains in the inner maximum can be written as $y^{*}(x^{*})$.